# data other than texts in R package

Tags: r, package

I am really new to developing packages in R. I have read that I can include data in data/ folder which would be accessible to users. However, all examples I have seen are text files. Is that possible to include a shapefile in the package? Where and how I should include it?

I really appreciate your time. 
Thanks

Comment: If somebody strolls along and gives you a "RTFM" type response... this is the manual they want you to read. It should jump the relevant section https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In the `data/` directory, as you have read.

Comment: There is an online book from Hadley that covers building packages and should have more detail.  http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: I have read this manual, but I was not sure if it will work for shapefiles also. I will check more carefully. Thanks!

Comment: I would also look at other packages with shape files to see what they have done https://github.com/cran

Comment: That is a great idea! I will.